# Why $f(x)=\pi$ is a rational function? Is a constant function a polynomial even though the constant is a transcendental?

Tags: rational-functions

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function) said

> A constant function such as $f(x) = π$ is a rational function since
> constants are polynomials. The function itself is rational, even
> though the value of $f(x)$ is irrational for all x.

But the definition stated:
A function ${\displaystyle f(x)}$ is called a rational function if and only if it can be written in the form
$${\displaystyle f(x) = {\frac {P(x)}{Q(x)}}}$$
where ${\displaystyle P\,}$ and ${\displaystyle Q\,}$ are polynomial functions of ${\displaystyle x\,}$ and ${\displaystyle Q\,}$ is not the zero function. The domain of ${\displaystyle f\,}$ is the set of all values of ${\displaystyle x\,}$ for which the denominator ${\displaystyle Q(x)\,}$ is not zero.

We can rewrite $f(x)=\pi$ as $f(x)=\frac{\pi}{1}$

I could agree if $1$ is a polynomial since it's a non-zero constant function that is a polynomial of degree 0. But $\pi$ is a trancendental number here. I mean, i never saw a polynomial with a constant of $\pi$. Can you explain it to me?

Thanks.

Comment: *"i never saw a polynomial with a constant of $\pi$"* ... Okay, $$x^3-2 x^2+17x+\pi$$ Now you have! :)

Comment: I think OP has incorrectly assumed polynomials must have integer coefficients.

Comment: @SenZen Honestly yes. now I realize that my question is very embarrassing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\pi$ is just a number here, we could calculate in a $\pi$-based number system, it would be a constant still.

Rational function means that it is a fraction of of two polynomials, now whether you take $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$ or even $\mathbb{Q}$ it doesn't matter because the terms rational number and rational function address different issues.

For example let's say you have the function $\pi f(x)$, how do you know this is rational or not?

f(x) could be a constant function or a $\dfrac{x}{\pi}$, the important part is that it satisfies the form
$$a_{n} x^n+a_{n-1} x^{n-1}+...+a_0 \hspace{6mm} \text{where } a_i \in \text{arbitrary } \mathbb{F} \text{ (field)}$$, then it's a polynomial. From which you can constuct *rational functions*.

Answer (score 1):

$\pi$ is a polynomial of degree $0$ of $\mathbb R[x]$. Therefore, the constant real map equal to $\pi$ is a rational function. **Which doesn't mean that $\pi$ is a rational number.**

The difficulty is that we are (abusively) naming two different objects as $\pi$:

- The real number.
- A real map.

Comment: It's not all that abusive. Rational numbers are the fraction field of the integers. Rational functions are the fraction field of the polynomials. Or less abstractly, rational numbers are ratios of numbers (integers, specifically), rational functions are ratios of functions (polynomial ones, specifically).

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) = \pi$ is a *polynomial function*. The coeficients in it do not have to be integers for it to be a polynomial. Yet, the *number* $\pi$ is irrational.

There are differences between a rational *function* and a rational *number*.